# Wildcard sub.domain.tld redirect to domain.tld/sub

Tags: apache, apache2, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I currently have a wild card subdomain with this on apache:

```
<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/web/domaine.tld/www
    ServerName domaine.tld
    ServerAlias *.domaine.tld
    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/web/domaine.tld/%1
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/domaine.tld/access.log combined
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/domaine.tld/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

And need to have any subdomain like sub.domain.tld being redirected to domain.tld

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use Redirect via .htaccess

```
Redirect http://sub.domain.tld http://domain.tld
```